# Elasticsearch + Couch = still need to use a separate ruby client?

Tags: ruby, couchdb, elasticsearch

For some reason I'm having trouble finding an answer to this, but it's a really simple question.  Do I still need to use Tire or some other ruby elastic search client if I am using couch db with elastic search, or are the couch searches themselves acted upon the ES index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch has a couchdb river plugin that listens to the couchdb _update feed. So couchdb is unaware that elasticsearch is running. So to access elasticsearch you will still need some client, being Tire or whatever you want to choose.